# Named pipe client returns ACCESS DENIED but only after initial successful connections

Tags: c++, .net, vb.net, winapi, named-pipes

I have a VB.NET process (non-service) that runs as admin and acts as the named pipe server.  A DLL is injected into certain processes and the DLL attempts to connect to the server process.  This is all on the same host.

I'm getting an ACCESS_DENIED (5) error from the client however, it only occurs after the first two clients successfully connect to the server.  So, at least two can successfully connect then all other attempts are denied.

In my test VM, at least 4 instances of the pipe server are created so it doesn't seem to be a simple case of a busy pipe (which I would assume return STATUS_PIPE_BUSY instead of ACCESS_DENIED anyway).  I've also added the most permissive pipe security I can (WorldSid/FullControl) and it still fails.

Here is the server pipe code:

```
Private Sub PipeSetup() 
    For x = 1 To Environment.ProcessorCount  '4 in my test VM 
        t = New Thread(AddressOf PipeSetupProc)
        t.IsBackground = True
        t.Start()
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub PipeSetupProc() 
    Dim s As NamedPipeServerStream = Nothing
    Dim x As PipeSecurity = Nothing

    While True
        Try
            'I've made the access rule the most permissive possible
            'and I'm still getting ACCESS_DENIED from the client.

            x = New PipeSecurity()
            x.AddAccessRule(New PipeAccessRule(New SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, Nothing), 
                PipeAccessRights.FullControl, Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow))

            s = New NamedPipeServerStream(MY_PIPE_NAME, PipeDirection.InOut, NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances, 
                PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 4096, 4096, x)
            s.WaitForConnection()

            'Do stuff here...

            s.Close()
            s = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
           'logerror()
        End Try
    End While
End Sub
```

During DLLMain(), a connection attempt is made using the following call and this is where it fails with ACCESS_DENIED.

```
hPipe = CreateFileW(MY_PIPE_NAME, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, 
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH, 0);
```

Comment: What does C++ have to do with this?

Comment: The DLL is written in C++.

Comment: Doesn't seem relevant to the question. It's a DLL. They are all "C" at the end of the day.

Comment: The C++ DLL is where the error is.  Seems kind of relevant.

Comment: Either the DLL has a bug in it, in which case you'll need to speak 100% in terms of the C++ DLL, or the DLL is fine and your VB code has a bug. It is not both.

Comment: So you're saying I can't talk about the complete design?  It can only be one or the other?  Suddenly too much information is now a bad thing.  The problem is named pipes and I'm discussing my implementation and that requires talking about both sides of the pipe.

Comment: Because I know if I didn't, there'd be some other user saying "show all your code."

Comment: What I'm saying is this is VB code that *happens* to call a C++ DLL. Most people looking at the C++ tag are looking for C++ questions they can answer. I've added `[winapi]` as that might draw the right eyeballs to this question.

Comment: No, you initially made a snarky response.  Had you just changed the tag and left a comment stating as such it would of been much more constructive.

Answer (score 0):

Check your MY_PIPE_NAME on both sides. for c++ it should be similar to "\\.\pipe\MY_PIPE" and on vb side it is just "MY_PIPE".

If the data is always from vb to the dll, you can just declare a function in c++ to be called from vb (inside of an 'extern "c"').

```
_stdcall int Send2Cpp(char * msg, int length){ /*...*/}
```

I have a habit of defining my exports in a module.def. If you don't, add the nessasary dll export terms. Otherwise add a file module.def to your vs c++ project, contents

```
LIBRARY
    EXPORTS
        Send2Cpp
```

Then from vb, just add

```
Public Declare Function Send2Cpp Lib "mydll.dll" (byval S as byte, byval L as integer) as integer
```

You can also supply a callback from vb.

```
Public Delegate Function GetCppString(ByVal str As IntPtr)
Function LogC(ByVal LI As IntPtr, ByVal lc As Int64) As Int64
        Dim F(lc) As Byte
        Marshal.Copy(LI, F, 0, lc)
        Debug.Print(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(F))
End Function
'make sure these vars persist untill dll is done with pointer
'or you will get errors when they are GC'd
dim CBD as GetCppString=AddressOf(GetCppString)
dim CB_PTR as IntPtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(CBD)
```

Then you pas CB_PTR to a dll function, where you can call the function from their. In C++

```
typedef int(*send2vb)(char *, int);
void RegCB(send2vb f){ /*do something with function pointer*/}
```

In this case, add RegCB to your module.def and a declare in vb for it.
Then you have bidirectional comms between dll and vb. (off course you'd have to wire it all together. In your dllmain, just wait for the function pointer to be non-null before sending data.
P.S. I just mention this as it turns out to be much more efficient than pipes or similar, especially if you use functions that match your use case (in mine, it was video from a c++ dll to vb and back).

Comment: Thanks but pipe format is correct.  As I said, first two connections work and then it starts returning the error.  Also, the DLL is injected into a remote process.  To call a function in a remotely injected DLL would require creating remote threads for every call I need to make.  Unless I'm misunderstanding your suggestion, it seems less efficient than IPC.

Comment: Have you tried using a loopback socket. I forget what I was doing at the time, but pipes were causing me troubles so I ended up using TCP on localhost. Another option can be messages (postmessage). In particular look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-copydata

Comment: I had not thought about a loopback socket but I'll definitely look into it.  Thanks for the suggestion.